# Is Java instanceof operator considered reflection, and what defines reflection?

Tags: java, language-agnostic, language-features, reflection

I had a discussion with a coworker today, whether usage of using the Java operator `instanceof` is a kind of reflection. And the discussion quickly evolved into what actually defines reflection.

**So, what is the definition of reflection?**

**And is the usage of `instanceof` considered "using reflection" ?**

And in addition, if `instanceof` is considered reflection, then is polymorphism not also "using reflection"? If not, what is the difference?

Comment: You've pretty much answered your own question. How you define 'reflection' determines whether `instanceof` is an example of reflection. Certainly it is somewhere between normal data use and metadata use via `getClass()` & friends, but you can have workable definitions wither way.

Comment: Is the usage of `return` considered "structural programming"?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_%28computer_science%29) is the definition of reflection according to wikipedia:

> In computer science, reflection is the process by which a computer
>   program can **observe (do type introspection)** and modify its own
>   structure and behavior at runtime.

I couldn't have said it better myself and highlighted the important part for your question. That said, yes, `instanceof` is considered using reflection. The program *observes* its structure and conducts *[type introspection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection)*.

Comment: Can getting the type of a variable be considered 'introspection'? :) A simple `if ( true )` also 'observes' the true value.

Comment: I see the wikipedia page on type introspection confirms your statement. Thinking about it, actually thinking of `instanceof` as reflection is a good thing. When it is not used for reflection purposes it usually indicates a code smell.

Comment: Your example can't be considered introspection. It's just a value being checked and compared. The type only matters to the compiler (and not even in all languages). Your little program isn't observing itself and its types. "Can getting the type of a variable be considered 'introspection'?" Yes, this can be considered introspection.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: The difference is that `if (true)` looks at a *value*, not at a *type*. That's why it's not considered reflection.

Comment: @Steven Jeuris: `if` statement is a flow control statement. Sure it observers value, but takes immediate action after observation is complete. And you can't do anything about what happens after observation is complete. This isn't reflection in my book.

Comment: @sleske: The reason why I mentioned it was because observing a type is such a rudimentary principle. Without it there would be no polymorphism. Technically speaking this means a simple override could also be considered reflection (or at least results in). Do not forget the second part of the definition: **and modify its own structure and behavior at runtime.** All in all I upvoted this answer (check my second comment), but I do understand where the question from the OP came from. ;p

Comment: According to that definition of reflection, would normal polymorphism not also be a kind of reflection?

Comment: @Jacek: You can't do much more after **just** using `instanceof` either, it also just controls flow.

Comment: @bjarkef: I would say "no", as the virtual dispatch used by polymorphism is done implicitly by the language itself, rather than the application code explicitly examining the object in question to identify its characteristics.

Comment: @Dave Sherohman: I'd also add that most of the work (setting up jump tables, etc) is done at compile time, not run time.

Answer (score 14):

For the sake of clarity, I would consider two answers.

**Theoretically**, `instanceof` is a form of reflection, as explained in [Falcon's answer](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/106362/is-java-instanceof-operator-considered-reflection-and-what-defines-reflection/106363#106363).

> In computer science, reflection is the process by which a computer
>   program can observe (do type introspection) and modify its own
>   structure and behavior at runtime.

However, **practically**, when a programmer talks about using reflection he usually refers to much more than just checking whether a variable is of a certain type. This is such a rudimentary concept, without which, [polymorphism wouldn't be possible](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection).

Do note that using `instanceof` often indicates a code smell, and proper polymorphism can often be used instead.

Comment: +1 for the potential code smell - not always, just the potential

Answer (score 3):

Since the other answers, the definition in Wikipedia has been changed (I happen to agree with this change, but I wasn't the one who made it) to remove the part in parentheses:

> In computer science, reflection is the ability of a computer program to examine, introspect, and modify its own structure and behavior at runtime.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_introspection also specifically says

> Introspection should not be confused with reflection

I wouldn't consider `instanceof` to fall under the first definition: the program examines a value, not its own structure, and it doesn't involve any values representing program structure (in Java: `java.lang.Class`, `java.reflect.Method`, etc.); the hallmark of reflection is working with such values.

Answer (score 2):

You might be interesting in the following article: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/ALT/Reflection/

The key in this article is a code snippet where they simulate the "instanceof" keyword by using the "isInstance" method of the "Class" class, which is part of the reflection feature of Java.

Comment: Nice explanation for Java.

Answer (score -5):

YES, "instanceof" operator its a form of reflection. The previous answers tell you why.

"Reflection" or "object / class introspection" is a hype these days, but several programming languages have use some of that concept, from some time.

DOT NET (Java clone), (mis) uses a lot.

Comment: Uuuuhm, … dude?

Comment: Your first sentence is correct, and redundant in the face of previous answers. The rest is just wrong.